# Combining cordapp jars

Tags: corda

Let's assume that I have deployed 2 cordapps in production: `cordapp-a.jar` and `cordapp-b.jar`.
Can I combine those 2 jars in the next release, i.e keep states and contracts of both jars in a single jar without changing structure and the packages of any of the states/contracts?
I am using `WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by combing the jars?

Comment: Tested it out myself - yes it is possible. In my case it happened that some classes that are used in states were in a different jar (using Corda 3). Corda 4 does not like it. So for my application to work with Corda 4 I had to combine those 2 jars.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. You need to take care of the constraints. You could learn more about constraints here: https://www.corda.net/blog/contract-upgrades-and-constraints-in-corda/

Since you are using `WhitelistedByZoneAttachmentConstraint` you could perform an implicit upgrade. You need to add the hash of the new jar to the network-parameter.

For `HashConstraint`, you don't have any option but to perform an explicit upgrade.

Using `SignatureConstraint` would be even simpler, you just need to make sure that the jars are signed by the same key.